# Lily-Solr-HBase Integration

Tags: solr, hbase, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to integrate lily-solr-hbase .

I'm using Hortonworks distribution (2.4 version) 
Solr (5.2.1 version)
Lily (2.0 version)

I'm following the lily documentation from official link :
http://docs.ngdata.com/lily-docs-2_0/414-lily/432-lily.html

But while running the steps as mentioned to start the lily server .. I'm getting the below exception .

```
[root@BAN-SDU-OVS2-VM7 lily-2.0]# bin/lily-server
[INFO ][11:32:41,606][main      ] org.kauriproject.runtime.info - Starting the Kauri Runtime.
[INFO ][11:32:42,163][main      ] org.kauriproject.runtime.info - Reading module configurations of 12 modules.
[INFO ][11:32:43,152][main      ] org.kauriproject.runtime.info - Starting the modules.
[INFO ][11:32:43,162][main      ] org.kauriproject.runtime.info - Starting module pluginregistry - /root/lily-2.0/lily-2.0/lily-2.0/lib/org/lilyproject/lily-pluginregistry-impl/2.0/lily-pluginregistry-impl-2.0.jar
[INFO ][11:32:44,203][main      ] org.kauriproject.runtime.info - Starting module general - /root/lily-2.0/lily-2.0/lily-2.0/lib/org/lilyproject/lily-general-module/2.0/lily-general-module-2.0.jar
org.kauriproject.runtime.KauriRTException: Error constructing module defined at /root/lily-2.0/lily-2.0/lily-2.0/lib/org/lilyproject/lily-general-module/2.0/lily-general-module-2.0.jar
        at org.kauriproject.runtime.module.build.ModuleBuilder.buildInt(ModuleBuilder.java:152)
        at org.kauriproject.runtime.module.build.ModuleBuilder.build(ModuleBuilder.java:55)
        at org.kauriproject.runtime.KauriRuntime.start(KauriRuntime.java:240)
        at org.kauriproject.runtime.cli.KauriRuntimeCli.run(KauriRuntimeCli.java:292)
        at org.kauriproject.runtime.cli.KauriRuntimeCli.main(KauriRuntimeCli.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.kauriproject.launcher.RuntimeCliLauncher.run(RuntimeCliLauncher.java:79)
        at org.kauriproject.launcher.RuntimeCliLauncher.launch(RuntimeCliLauncher.java:58)
        at org.kauriproject.launcher.RuntimeCliLauncher.main(RuntimeCliLauncher.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hbaseConfiguration' defined in KAURI-INF/spring/services.xml in /root/lily-2.0/lily-2.0/lily-2.0/lib/org/lilyproject/lily-general-module/2.0/lily-general-module-2.0.jar: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.lilyproject.server.modules.general.HadoopConfigurationFactoryImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for  after 1 tries.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.kauriproject.runtime.module.build.ModuleBuilder.buildInt(ModuleBuilder.java:89)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.lilyproject.server.modules.general.HadoopConfigurationFactoryImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for  after 1 tries.
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:248)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for  after 1 tries.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:914)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:820)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:788)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:213)
        at org.lilyproject.server.modules.general.HadoopConfigurationFactoryImpl.waitOnHBase(HadoopConfigurationFactoryImpl.java:67)
        at org.lilyproject.server.modules.general.HadoopConfigurationFactoryImpl.<init>(HadoopConfigurationFactoryImpl.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
        ... 28 more
Startup failed. Will try to shutdown and exit.
[INFO ][11:33:45,632][main      ] org.kauriproject.runtime.info - Shutting down the modules.
[INFO ][11:33:45,633][main      ] org.kauriproject.runtime.info - Stopping the restservice manager.
```

Can anyone help so as how to  fix this and proceed ?

Thanks in advance .